# MVC4 Avoid repeating model field length validation in viewmodel

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following entity in my application (using EF6 codefirst).

```
public partial class Staff
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class StaffMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Staff>
{
    public StaffMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Username)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(60);

        this.Property(t => t.Password)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(60);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Staff");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Username).HasColumnName("Username");
        this.Property(t => t.Password).HasColumnName("Password");
        this.Property(t => t.IsAdmin).HasColumnName("IsAdmin");
        this.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive");
    }
}
```

I have the following viewmodel created for adding and editing staff members:

```
public class StaffViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Description("Is Admin")]
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    [Description("Is Active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

You will see that the Username field is limited to 60 characters in the EF-generated StaffMap class. If the user enters a string of over 60 characters, the data validation passes ok, but a data exception is thrown further down the chain when attempting to save.

I want the viewmodel to alert the user that the maximum length of the field is 60 characters, but I want to avoid adding extra field length validation in the viewmodel.

The way I see it, field lengths are already specified once in the domain, so it would be nice to get the viewmodel to use the domain field lengths.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: What is exactly the problem of adding a validation rule to a different model? One of the points of view models is that you can separate database validation and input validation in your views. You can use a framework like FluentValidation for this as suggested by phil.

Comment: The problem is that I would need to repeat the field length validation in several places (once per view model using that field). Furthermore, if I change a field length in the database, I must then attempt to find every viewmodel based on that field too!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this [FluentValidation for MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

Comment: It looks like I still have to define it a second time with this though, when in fact it has already been defined once in the domain. Or does it import it for me from the domain?

Comment: define it somewhere add the fluent.api Input is dragged from the other location. so reading off an attribute on the core model looks best to me.  I use fluent api in EF and get custom attributes to configure it

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it violates DRY if you need to put the length and "requiredness" in both the model and view model.  It would be better if that could be avoided.  I'm also looking for a solution for this.  Did you give up?

Comment: Yes I gave up in the end :(